# Undefined offset: 0 - PHP Errors in Ajax Response

Tags: php, wordpress, undefined-index

I am sure this is a simple fix, but I can't seem to figure it out. Error is `Undefined offset: 0`

My code actually works, but getting this error in the browser console. I've tried looking at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef) and declaring the variable, however it's still triggering the error. Am I missing something obvious?

I have tried declaring by adding in `$product_id= $_POST['id'] ?? '';` and also `$product_id = 0;` but they don't seem to be making any change.

Can anyone assist me please?

```
    function checking_items() {
    if( isset($_POST['id']) && $_POST['id'] > 0 ){
        // Initialising variables
        $counts     = array();
        $product_id = $_POST['id'];
        $categories = array('protein', 'pantry');

        // Loop through cart for product categories count
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if ( has_term( $categories[0], 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
               $counts[0] += $cart_item['quantity'];
            if ( has_term( $categories[1], 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id'] ) )
               $counts[1] += $cart_item['quantity'];
        }

        // Return the product category count that belongs to the added item
        if( has_term( $categories[0], 'product_cat', $product_id ) )
            echo json_encode(array(strtoupper($categories[0]) => $counts[0])); // Returned value to jQuery
        if( has_term( $categories[1], 'product_cat', $product_id ) )
            echo json_encode(array(strtoupper($categories[1]) => $counts[1])); // Returned value to jQuery
    }

    die(); // To avoid server error 500
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, errors like that normally come with a line number to tell you where the error occured. Can you identify which line is generating the error, it is easier for us then. So we dont have to compile all the code you show in our heads

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from `$_POST['id']`? You have a hard coded reference to `$counts[0]`. Could it be coming from that? If you update your question with the complete error message it might help.

Comment: I am not 100% sure it's coming from `$_POST['id']`. Apologies, I'm still finding my away around the browser console. I have updated question with error screenshot.

Comment: Can you tell us which line is line 14, as you may not have actually included all the lines from this script

Comment: Line 14 is `$counts[0] += $cart_item['quantity'];`

Comment: Are you sure `$counts[0]` actually exist? please var_dump it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to properly initiate `$counts` as:

```
$counts = array(0,0);
```

because you are currently trying to increment a non-existent position:

```
// This doesn't work when position zero doesn't exist.
$counts[0] += $cart_item['quantity'];
```

Same thing applies to your `$counts[1] +=` line.

Comment: Does `$counts = array(0,0);` need to be initiated outside of the IF statement?

Comment: It simply needs to exist before you try to use it. It's fine exactly where you have placed it.

Comment: That worked! Thanks @MonkeyZeus.